# React object property in state reference on another object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react and I want to archieve this. I have grid in my page where it displays some data from array. I want to have defined multiple objects in my state as it is shown below.

Properties `take` and `skip` in `query` has to be set by `pagingOptions`

Property `filter` in `query` has to be set by `filter` object

Right now it throws me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

How can I set those properties to their values?

My component with those states looks like this:

```
this.state = {
        // filter for my grid view
        filter: {   
            id: 1,
            status: ""
            etc....
        },
        // paging options for grid 
        pagingOptions:{
            pageSize: 5,
            skip: 0
        },
        //this represents query which is send to my api
        query:{
            collectionName: "",
            filter: this.state.filter // here it throws an error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
            sort: {},
            projection: {},
            take: this.state.pagingOptions.pageSize, // it will throw error also here since its same approach as filter
            skip: this.state.pagingOptions.skip // it will throw error also here since its same approach as filter
            includeTotalCount: true,
            context: null,
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you add the code that's throwing that error?

Comment: I edited question where it happens

Comment: based on @James  provided , Please find here https://codesandbox.io/s/w7yvmpwp5w

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Exactly what I need, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to reference a property of `this.state` before `this.state` has a value (it's `undefined`, hence the error message you mentioned).

To work around this you could add the `query` property to the state object after you've defined it:

```
this.state = {
  // ...
};

this.state.query = {
  // ...
};
```